# How to write a REGEX for accepting numbers, + and -

Tags: asp.net, regex

Can anybody help me to write a regex expression which accpets  -

1. Numbers
2. +
3. -
4. Total number characters should be 20.

Comment: -1 What have you tried? Did it work? If not, why not? (And what did you look for on SO .. ? You could probably use one or more answers as a starting point .. also, does it *need* to be a [single] regular expression?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use character set `[...]`

here you are:
    `[-+\d]{20}`

Comment: Thanks. But this accepts alphabets. How can i avoid this? I am really new to this regex and have to complete soon . Thanks for ur answer.

Comment: accepts alphabets? \d only match digit. Maybe you should provide some sample text.